# Unsubscribe an observable when user is "afk"

Tags: angular

Is it possible to check if the user haven't done any action in the app window for a while and execute a command like unsubscribing an observable?

I have an observable which runs an API call every x seconds, and I don't wish that users who are away and not making any actions in the app - will consume calls from my API.

Hope someone has a solution, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is [ifvisible.js](https://github.com/serkanyersen/ifvisible.js) to check if a user is idle or active on the page. With this information you can unsubscribe from an observable.

Comment: There is no reference about how to use it in Angular 2, Do you have any idea?